# How to add field and manipulate value to a class with ByteBuddy?

Tags: java, code-generation, bytecode, byte-buddy

I'd like to add the following code to existing classes using ByteBuddy. Given an existing class `SomeSample` I want to turn this into the follwoing:

```
class SomeSample {

  private @Transient boolean isNew = true;

  public boolean isNew() {
    return isNew;
  }

  @PrePersist
  @PostLoad
  void markNotNew() {
    this.isNew = false;
  }
}
```

### Original attempt

I can get the field and methods added properly. What I cannot really get to work is the assignment of the value. I've learned that I need to augment all existing constructors of the class I want to augment as technically an assignment declared like this is compiled into the constructors.

I've created the following helper:

```
public class Helper {

  @OnMethodExit
  public static void initField(@FieldValue(value = "isNew", readOnly = false) boolean value) {
    value = !value;
  }
}
```

and tried to assign this as follows:

```
builder.constructor(ElementMatchers.any())
  .intercept(Advice.to(Helper.class));
```

I would've expected the advice to be added at the end of the original declarations but during the build I receive the following error:

```
Failed to transform class files in …: Cannot call super (or default) method for public ….SomeSample()
```

### Alternative approach

Instead of flipping the value of the field I thought I could also stay with the default (`false`) and negate the value returned from the generated `isNew()` method. If I change my helper to this:

```
public class Helper {

  public static boolean isNew(@FieldValue(value = "isNew") boolean value) {
    return !value;
  }
}
```

When I change my method generating code for `isNew()` to the following:

```
builder = builder.defineMethod("isNew", boolean.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Helper.class));
```

I get:

```
None of [public static boolean ….Helper.isNew(boolean)] allows for delegation from public boolean SomeSample.isNew()
```

Any idea?

Comment: `@FieldValue(value = "isNew")`, are you using the `Advice` version of the annotation here by accident?

Comment: ‍♂️ That was indeed the case and seems to solve the delegation error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was maybe an unfortunate API choice but you can use `Advice` both as decorator and interceptor. What you likely would want to would be to set:

```
builder = builder.visit(Advice.to(Helper.class).on(isConstructor()))
```

This adds the code around the existing code. With the suggested approach, you replace the method around a call to the original implementation. If you define a new method, such an implementation does not exist and the error you are seeing is yielded.

Comment: That already gets me further, thanks. I am now stuck with `….SomeSample() does not define an index 0`. Full stack trace in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/odrotbohm/7e0cf3416cbb337a8ad45d5564ef9248).

Comment: that indicates you are using the incorrect annotation and advice falls back to the default of mapping the argunent with the same parameter index.

Comment: Once in untangled my code trying to get `Helper` work with both the constructor *and* the `isNew()` method using the correct annotation, everything works as you describe. Once again, a big thank you for helping out! ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

```
builder = builder
  .defineField("isNew", boolean.class, Visibility.PRIVATE)
  .annotateField(yourTransientAnnotationLiteral);

builder = builder
  .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .intercept(MethodCall.invokeSuper()
               .andThen(FieldAccessor.of("isNew")
                          .setsValue(Boolean.TRUE)));

builder = builder
  .defineMethod("isNew", boolean.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .intercept(FieldAccessor.of("isNew"));

builder = builder
  .defineMethod("markNotNew", TypeDescription.VOID, Visibility.PACKAGE_PRIVATE)
  .intercept(FieldAccessor.of("isNew")
               .setsValue(Boolean.FALSE));
```

This is untested (I'm particularly not sure about the implementation of the `isNew()` method) but I hope gives you an idea of one general way to do this programmatically without using `@Advice` or other higher-level mechanisms.

Comment: That's helpful, too, thanks. The issue I have with that approach is that I need to add the setting of the field to *every* constructor already present in the class.

Comment: So in that case instead of `defineConstructor` in my example, use `constructor` (https://javadoc.io/static/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.19/net/bytebuddy/dynamic/DynamicType.Builder.html#constructor-net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher-) and you should be good.